# Sort AlphaNumeric with structured references in Excel

Tags: excel, sorting, alphanumeric

I Have an Excel Sheet with data that looks like that.

```
Data
x=1.1
x=11.2
x=10.3
x=1.4
x=2.5;2.6
x=2.1
x=4.7
x=6.8
x=6.2;6.3
x=1.10
```

What i want to do is, to sort the List that it Looks like that.

```
DataSort
x=1.1
x=1.4
x=1.10
x=2.1
x=2.5;2.6
x=4.7
x=6.2;6.3
x=6.8
x=10.3
x=11.2
```

I tried to do that with that Formula

```
=LEFT(Tabelle1[[#this row];[Data]];2) & TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(Tabelle1[[#this row];[Data]];LEFT(Tabelle1[[#this row];[Data]];2);"");"#0.0#")
```

But that did not work.
Can someone give me a hint to the right Direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution to the Problem is:

```
=LEFT(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(";";A1));LEFT(A1;FIND(";";A1;1)-1);A1);2)&TEXT(--MID(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(";";A1));LEFT(A1;FIND(";";A1;1)-1);A1);3;FIND(".";IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(";";A1));LEFT(A1;FIND(";";A1;1)-1);A1)&".")-3);"000;@") &TEXT(--MID(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(";";A1));LEFT(A1;FIND(";";A1;1)-1);A1);FIND(".";IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(";";A1));LEFT(A1;FIND(";";A1;1)-1);A1)&".")+1;99);"000;@")
```

Answer (score 1):

Copy the data into a new column say `B`
If you are using excel 2007 or higher, go to data tab --> text to columns option after selecting your data in `B`

Here you can choose delimited and it will separate your data into 2 columns.
Then apply the sorting based on this column

Comment: Thanks for the Tip. But that is not working. If i have a number like "t=1.10" it becomes "1.1"

Answer (score 1):

In an unused column to the right, use this formula starting in row 2,

```
=LEFT(A2, 2)&TEXT(--MID(A2, 3, FIND(".", A2&".")-3), "000;@")&TEXT(--MID(A2, FIND(".", A2&".")+1, 99), "000;@")
```

Fill down as necessary then sort conventionally using the *helper* column as the primary sort key.

[image: Sort with Helper column]

Comment: Thx. I will give it a try. But right now i have Problems to get the Formula working

Comment: The Code Woks but know i have a problem. There are Gruonumbers Like "x=13.5;13.6". Do you have a tip for that?

Comment: The Solution was: =LEFT(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(";";A1));LEFT(A1;FIND(";";A1;1)-1);A1);2)&TEXT(--MID(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(";";A1));LEFT(A1;FIND(";";A1;1)-1);A1);3;FIND(".";IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(";";A1));LEFT(A1;FIND(";";A1;1)-1);A1)&".")-3);"000;@") &TEXT(--MID(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(";";A1));LEFT(A1;FIND(";";A1;1)-1);A1);FIND(".";IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(";";A1));LEFT(A1;FIND(";";A1;1)-1);A1)&".")+1;99);"000;@")

Answer (score 1):

If you put a 0 prior to the numbers,  that would take care of it.

X=01.1

Or,  in a convoluted way, split the column as recommended above,  sort the way you want and then reassemble. I would also create a column with the right 1-n sequence, just in case I need to sort in a particular way, but the come back to the original sort.